# How to scroll down in appium

Tags: c#, automation, appium

I know when i want to scroll down to specific element in appium use the following
`driver.ScrollTo(value);` 
but this value is changed every time and can't detect it i can not use this value to scroll until find the element, but this element is the last element in my page and number of element in the page is changed between user and another. 
So, there is any other way to scroll down till the end of the page ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use xpath to find the element without using value(as it is dynamic)

then use that element to scroll,

```
WebElement element = driver.findElementByXpath("xpath_of_element");
((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", element);
```

Just post the DOM of that page..i'll give you efficient xpath so even if your dom is dynamic that locator will work...

Answer (score 0):

`scrollToExact` and `scrollTo` method is depricated since JAVA client version 4.0.0 (https://github.com/appium/java-client/blob/master/README.md).

You can use `UiScrollable` and `UiSelector` and their methods to scroll any page (https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/test/uiautomator/UiScrollable.html).

Example of JAVA code (please edit it with C# syntax):

> @AndroidFindBy (uiAutomator = "new UiScrollable(new
>   UiSelector()).scrollIntoView(new UiSelector().textContains(\"Question
>   \"))")

If you want scroll to the bottom of page, please create method that will do several steps to find last element of page, otherwise you will get an error (Element not found)

Answer (score 0):

Use touch action instead

TouchAction t = new TouchAction(driver);

```
     t.longPress(element(source)).moveTo(element(destination)).release().perform();
```